# Como testar Controller com JUnit?

Tags: nullpointerexception, controller, java-8, junit

Estou testando a URL assim

```
package br.com.aluguel.de.carros.unidade.usuario;

import br.com.aluguel.de.carros.endereco.Endereco;
import br.com.aluguel.de.carros.usuario.Usuario;
import br.com.aluguel.de.carros.usuario.UsuarioService;
import org.hamcrest.core.Is;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

public class TestaUsuarioController {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    UsuarioService service;

    @Test
    public void testaUrlUsuario() throws Exception{
        Endereco e = new Endereco();
        e.setComplemento("complemento 1");
        e.setId(1l);
        e.setBairro("bairro 2");
        e.setCidade("cidade 3");
        e.setEstado("estado 4");
        e.setLogradouro("logradouro 5");
        e.setNumero(6);

        Usuario u = new Usuario();
        u.setPerfil("cliente");
        u.setId(1l);
        u.setNome("Arthur");
        u.setCnh("000");
        u.setCpf("111");
        u.setEmail("teste@gmail.com");
        u.setEndereco(e);
        u.setSenha("senha 2");
        u.setTelefone("4678612");

        given(service.usuario(1l)).willReturn(Optional.of(u));
        mvc.perform(get("/usuario").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.u", Is.is(u.getPerfil())));
    }
}
```

Ele me retorna NullPointerException

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at br.com.aluguel.de.carros.unidade.usuario.TestaUsuarioController.testaUrlUsuario(TestaUsuarioController.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Apontando um erro na linha 48 que é meu given:

```
given(service.usuario(1l)).willReturn(Optional.of(u));
```

Alguém me salva??!!

Comment: Você só vai conseguir utilizar `@Autowired` quando existir um contexto do Spring criado, sugiro seguir algum tutorial para utilizar `@SpringBootTest` por exemplo, faltam configurações para seu teste funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Arthur, coloca @MockBean em vez de @Autowired no seu service.
Você não vai conseguir mockar ele com Autowired

Também coloca essas annotations no topo da sua classe de teste que são necessarias pra subir os contextos que o MockMvc precisa pra rodar:

@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.cass)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@WebMvcTest(YourController.class)